# Yeoman - Update node modules in app folder

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I use Yeoman for creating and managing my apps;
after app is created, in the app's folder there are several node_modules installed (bower, grunt, grunt-cli ...)

What have I to do if I want all this node modules to be updated to their respective latest versions?

Now I manually go inside node modules' folders and run

```
npm update
```

one by one; but i wonder if there is a better way to do that...

Yeoman creates a package.json in the project's root folder; here's the file content:

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.2-0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.2.4",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-livereload": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.10",
    "grunt-regarde": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.1.0",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-ember-templates": "0.4.7",
    "grunt-neuter": "0.5.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

but if I run npm update, it says that there is no "repository field"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call "`npm update`" in your root project folder, right where your package.json file is. It will check for updates in all local and global modules.

Yeoman should create the package.json, so it should exist anyway.

Comment: I've edited the question... Yes there is a package.json file, but running npm update I get an error (there is no repository field)

Comment: that´s interesting, i just opened a package.json of one of my projects (not created with yeoman though), did not specify a repository and it works perfectly fine...

Comment: maybe the problem is only with one specific module?  do you get an error or just a warning? because a warning you could just ignore, see here: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3568

Comment: btw, i am using the newest node version (v0.10.21) and npm 1.3.8

Comment: After updating node from 0.10.12 to 0.10.21, i get no more errors or warnings but simply nothing happens; for example, i run "npm update" from within a folder that has grunt 0.4.1 installed and nothing happens (grunt is not updated to 0.4.2); i've also tried to change grunt version in the devDependencies section in the package.json file and run "npm update" again, but still not working...

Comment: according to http://gruntjs.com/, the stable version is 0.4.1 - maybe it only affects stable ones?